# Why my Bluetooth app is not discovering devices with Xamarin C#?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am building a Bluetooth application in Xamarin Android and my app has three BroadcastReceivers. One for detecting when the adapter has started device discovery `ActionDiscoveryStarted`, a second one when a Bluetooth device has been discovered `ActionFound` and a third one for detecting when the device discovery has finished `ActionDiscoveryFinished`. My application toasts a message to the user when an intent is intercepted from the system. Both the first and the third intents work from the screenshots below.
[image]

[image]
Now I have a Bluetooth device here and it is the laptop am typing this on, I expected my app to detect my laptop and toast the device found message from the second broadcast receiver but that is not working and it shows 0 devices found. I have all the location and bluetooth permissions in my manifest like

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

and the code for the three broadcast receivers is listed below

**DeviceDiscoveryStarted receiver**

```
    //register a broadcast for listening when the device discovery process has started
    [IntentFilter(new[] { BluetoothAdapter.ActionDiscoveryStarted })]
    [BroadcastReceiver(Enabled = true, Exported = false)]
    public class DeviceDiscoveryStarted : BroadcastReceiver
    {
        public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            if (intent.Action == BluetoothAdapter.ActionDiscoveryStarted)
            {
                Toast.MakeText(context,"Bluetooth device discovery started",ToastLength.Long).Show();
                
            }
        }
    }
```

This receiver is not working despite having mylaptop bluetooth on

**DeviceFound receiver**

```
//register a listener for listening when a new bluetooth device has been discovered
    [IntentFilter(new[] { BluetoothDevice.ActionFound })]
    [BroadcastReceiver(Enabled = true, Exported = false)]
    public class DeviceFound : BroadcastReceiver
    {
        private List<BluetoothDevice> _bluetoothDevices;
        //declare the default constructor
        public DeviceFound()
        {
            
        }
        //declare the custom constructor and require the bluetooth device list from the other class
        public DeviceFound(List<BluetoothDevice> devicelist)
        {
            _bluetoothDevices = devicelist;
        }
        public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            if (intent.Action == BluetoothDevice.ActionFound)
            {
                //toast to the user that a bluetooth device has been found
                Toast.MakeText(context,"New device found",ToastLength.Long).Show();
                //get the device as an extra parcelable
                BluetoothDevice device =(BluetoothDevice) intent.GetParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.ExtraDevice);
                //if device is not equal to null append to the list
                if(device!= null)
                    _bluetoothDevices.Add(device);
            }
        }
    }
```

**ActionDiscoveryFinished reciever**

```
 //program a receiver for the intent ACTION_DISCOVERY_COMPLETED
    [IntentFilter(new[] { BluetoothAdapter.ActionDiscoveryFinished })]
    [BroadcastReceiver(Enabled = true, Exported = false)]
    public class DiscoveryFinished : BroadcastReceiver
    {
        private List<BluetoothDevice> _devices;
        //default ctor
        public DiscoveryFinished()
        {
            
        }
        public DiscoveryFinished(List<BluetoothDevice> devices)
        {
            _devices = devices;
        }
        public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            if (intent.Action == BluetoothAdapter.ActionDiscoveryFinished)
            {
                //toast to the user that the discovery has been finished
                Toast.MakeText(context,"Discovery has finished...Found"+_devices.Count,ToastLength.Short).Show();
            }
        }
    }
```

and this is how I registered my receivers in the OnCreate of my app

```
            //register a receiver for a bluetooth device discovery process started
            DeviceDiscoveryStarted started = new DeviceDiscoveryStarted();
            RegisterReceiver(started, new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ActionDiscoveryStarted));
            //register a receiver for a bluetooth device discovered
            DeviceFound found = new DeviceFound(_bluetoothDevices);
            RegisterReceiver(found, new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ActionFound));
            //register listener for discovery finished
            DiscoveryFinished finished = new DiscoveryFinished(_bluetoothDevices);
            IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ActionDiscoveryFinished);
            RegisterReceiver(finished, filter);
```

Comment: It looks like a permission issue, I need user permission for the following permissions
`The BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE, BLUETOOTH_CONNECT, and BLUETOOTH_SCAN permissions are runtime permissions. Therefore, you must explicitly request user approval in your app before you can look for Bluetooth devices`

Answer (score 0):

The app is working fine, the reason as to why it was not discovering the laptop as a bluetooth device is because it was already a paired device, I made the laptop forget my phone and the device found broadcast receiver worked.